# How to use a git repository as a svn:external?

Tags: git, svn, external, git-submodules

SVN offers external source link via `svn:external` feature. And I'm using a module from a Git repository. Can I use this Git repository as an external source?

My module Git repository is in Github. So Github specific way is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Github announced SVN support.
https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support

I added my Github repository as a `svn:external` directly.

Comment: The problem I found with this is that it brings too many directories with it i.e. the trunk / branches / tags directories. You can just pull in the specific directory e.g. `svn co -N [repo]` and `svn up trunk` but then you're still left with 'trunk' in the path that was no good for me

Comment: Sadly, on 2024-01-08 GitHub removed this once very useful feature: https://github.blog/2023-01-20-sunsetting-subversion-support/

Answer (score 2):

A repository on Github can act like a Subversion repository.  See [this blog post about their improved SVN support](https://github.com/blog/966-improved-subversion-client-support).  It seems to be very slow, but it works.

**UPDATE** [Subversion support on GitHub ended Jan 2024](https://github.blog/changelog/2024-01-08-subversion-has-been-sunset/).

Another solution for putting a git repository inside a SVN repository would be to set svn:ignore on the nested repository directory and use a Makefile to clone and update the git repository.

```
cd svn-repository
svn propset svn:ignore gitdir .
```

Then do something like this to your `Makefile` or other build system.

```
GITREPO=git://github.com/schwern/perl5i.git
GITDIR=gitdir

all : $(GITDIR)

$(GITDIR)/.git :
    git clone $(GITREPO) $(GITDIR)

$(GITDIR) : $(GITDIR)/.git
    cd $(GITDIR) && git pull
```

First call to `make` will clone the git repository.  Subsequent calls will do an update.

I like this solution better.  It doesn't rely on the git repository being on Github nor does it rely on emulation.  The git repository can be worked on as a git repository rather than having to go through emulation where clashing concepts between git and SVN will likely cause problems.

Comment: As of January 8, 2024 Subversion support on GitHub.com was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the tarball or zipball from GitHub using this URL:

```
https://github.com/UserName/ProjectName/zipball/master
```

Or if you prefer tarballs:

```
https://github.com/UserName/ProjectName/tarball/master
```

They are snapshots of the code, zipped up.

Comment: But that way, you don't get the current versions of the Git repository, and it is only one way, not the way back from SVN checkout to the Git repository back.

Comment: The zipball is pretty up-to-date, actually, as it reflects changes made within the last few minutes. I think it's generated when you initialize the download and cached between commits.

Comment: But it will stay that the next few months, and will not be updated when doing a `svn update`, which is done if you bind an external resource by `svn:externals`.